# Database Diagram in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to create a diagram of SAS datasets in a SAS library, basically an equivalent of Database Diagram that can be created for database tables in SQL Server Management Studio. Can this be done using any of SAS applications?

Comment: It's possible to define foreign key constraints in sas datasets, but I don't think it's very common. If your data have foreign key constraints, you should be able to generate a diagram. But if not, I think the best you could do is list all the datasets in a library and vars in each dataset. Does your data have foreign keys defined?

Comment: @Quetin - Currently there is no FK defined in SAS but they could be added. How can I generate a diagram once foreign keys are in place?

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps ODBC connection would allow you to build it in Visio or similar generic ERD tool that can read data via odbc? I've never tried it. Haven't done more than play a little bit with PK/Fk definitions in sas. Maybe try asking over at communities.sas.com.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to build an entity relationship diagram to "visual" the schema for set of tables in your library. If you are looking just for documentation only, you can try Visio or MS-Access using OLEDB connection to read all table metadata from your library, however you need to build all the relationship including primary keys & etc.

If you are looking for building an ETL process, where maintaining entity relationship will be part of your ETL job, then Jetzler suggested ETL solution will be your tools, because once you build your process, the schema, e.g. star or snow-flake schema will be automatic generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

Data Integration Studio is the SAS solution for visual management of ETL/data integration. The processes are build in flow chart diagrams. It also offers some options to visualize your data models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am familiar with some ETL tasks and defining tables and libraries within DI Studio. Can you explain what option are available in DI Studio for visualisation of the tables within a library? I would like to create a diagram with all tables and their variables.